# Can I swap an Apple SSD from one laptop to another?

Tags: hardware, ssd, migration, data

I have a liquid spill on my previous MacBook Pro 2014 Retina 15ʺ MGXC2LL/A.
The logic board is dead and fixing it does not make any sense. But the SSD has all data saved and a technician told that it's fine and safe.

If I purchase another MacBook Pro 2014 MGXC2LL/A with same SSD, CPU etc, can I just switch the SSD card? I want to get my profile, apps and all data. 
Or is it too dangerous and it can wipe all the data? I heard that every piece of hardware have their own serial number and I can't just switch them between laptops.

Comment: Yes same computer same hardware.  Be careful though you would be surprised same year hardware can have difference in hardware though.

Comment: I swapped successfully between two exact models apple laptops. ( Same year, same model, same cpu and memory ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would probably work OK, but it would probably be easier to just mount the drive externally and copy your files over to the new machine. That way, you wouldn't need to open up the new machine and install the old SSD.

You could mount the SSD on the new machine with something like this: Seagate Backup Plus Desktop Thunderbolt Adapter [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B009HQCAPQ/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009HQCAPQ)

Comment: I just need to find the SSD reader which will have same socket as a MAC SSD card, and they cost over 100$

Comment: @Anton I'm pretty sure the SSD port is standardized. Just check if it's SATA II or III, etc.

Comment: @Anton It's either mSATA or M.2—can't tell which.  I recommend looking for an adapter that can handle both types, like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/ZTC-Thunder-Board-Adapter-ZTC-AD002/dp/B00KFRVVU6/ref=sr_1_3).

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it will work by just swapping the SSD. But remember a few things:

1. You will void the warranty by opening up the laptop
2. You might break the laptop if you are not experienced in opening it up.

I would just recommend a USB SSD drive enclosure like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015SGGV8A) (definitely not the best one but it works). Then transfer all the datas from the old SSD to the new one. Plus you can use the old SSD as an external storage.

Comment: Why it should become brick after replacing ssd? 
I opened my previous laptop huge amount of times.

Comment: @Anton if you feel confident about doing it, of course you can do it if you want.

Comment: I just want to know from technical side  will it work or not?
( Not including human factor)

Comment: @Anton yes it will work

Comment: It should work just fine.  But not with a 2016 Mac Book Pro.  Those have the HD and RAM basically welded to the computer.  Stick to 2015 or older and you should be good.